# Excel Query (find all + value of another cell in relation to results)

Tags: excel, excelquery

I need to search ALL cells for a value (VALUE A) and then output the value of all cells 7 cells above that contains the value (VALUE A).

For example, if I search for V01 in the screenshot attached, I want to see the results "Crème Fraîche 326 µg" and "Cheese (Cow's Milk) 224 µg AVERAGE"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ8KC.png)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you, or if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that should be easily adaptable to your usage case:

```
Sub messageAssembler()
    Dim message As String
    Dim startingLocation As String
    Dim searchLocation As Range
    Dim foundLocation As Range
    Dim cellCount As Range
    Dim searchValue As String
    searchValue = "V01"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A1").Select
    Set searchLocation = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set cellCount = searchLocation.Cells(searchLocation.Cells.Count)
    Set foundLocation = searchLocation.Find(what:=searchValue, after:=cellCount)
    If Not foundLocation Is Nothing Then
        startingLocation = foundLocation.Address
        foundLocation.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0).Select
        message = Chr(34) & ActiveCell & Chr(34)
        foundLocation.Activate
    Else
        GoTo noInstances
    End If
    Do Until foundLocation Is Nothing
        Set foundLocation = searchLocation.FindNext(after:=foundLocation)
        foundLocation.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0).Select
        If foundLocation.Address <> startingLocation Then
            message = message & " and " & Chr(34) & ActiveCell & Chr(34)
        Else: Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox message, vbOKOnly, "Search Result:"
Exit Sub
noInstances:
    MsgBox "The requested search value does not exist", vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

The code looks for the value that has been assigned to the string "searchValue"
If any instance of the assigned value is found, it begins assembling a message based on the cell that is 7 cells above the instance. It then loops through to locate all of the other instances, and adds the cells that are 7 above each instance to the message, seperating them with " and ".
Once completed, the result is displayed in a message box.

When the preceding macro is ran on the example spreadsheet you provided with the searchValue set to "V01" this is the result:
[image]